# I need to install a epson tm-u950 printer on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: installation, drivers, printing, epson

I need to know how to install an Epson tm-u950 printer on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I have been searching for around 3 months now.  Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I visited https://pos.epson.com/developers/techresdetails.htm?productpk=554 and downloaded the file from there at a painful 164KB/Sec. Everything there was for Windows!

Next I went to http://www.posmicro.com/recprinters/epson/epson%20drivers.htm No Joy!

After a lot more hunting around, I found http://www.javapos.com/devices.html May be of interest (go to section 4) JavaPOS ADK 1.82 supports the TM-U950 and can be installed on a Linux platform.

As I do not have this printer, I could be barking up the wrong tree!

I hope that this is of some help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Download [this](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=3839) driver, Chose TM Epson Slip on cups.
Although is only printing on one side for me, and not in the slip/journal side.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to print on both receipt and slip. You have to send the following ESC/POS commands to the printer.

```
# Select slip y receipt
printf "\x1Bc0\X03" > /dev/lp0
# Parallel printing on
printf "\x1Bz\X01" > /dev/lp0
```

In python you would do something like

```
printer = open('/dev/lp0', 'wb', 0)
printer.write(bytearray([0x1B, 0x43, 0x00, 0x03]))
printer.write(bytearray([0x1B, 0x7A, 0x01]))
printer.flush()
printer.close()
```

`/dev/lp0` is the parallel port. You could also write this commands to `/dev/ttySx` if the printer have a serial interface.

Hope this helps somebody.